# Post With Angular2 and Asp.Net Core Api Not Binding Params

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript, angular

I have this service in Angular 2

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

import { Hero } from './../model/hero';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

    private herosUrl = 'api/heroes';
    private http: Http;
    private writeHeaders: Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }    

    private post(hero: Hero) {

        return this.http
            .post(this.herosUrl, JSON.stringify(hero), { headers: this.writeHeaders })
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => res.json().data)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }    
}
```

and this is the Hero model in Typescript Angular

```
export class Hero {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
}
```

I want to send this data to an Api based on Asp.Net Core.
So, this is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Hero hero)
{
    try
    {
        _context.Heroes.Add(hero);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and here is my C# Hero model

```
public class Hero
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The request hits the server with success and return a 200 code.
The problem is that the body request is not binded, and it creates a new Hero, with empty values, not the values I've passed.

What I'm doing wrong???

Comment: Try `public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Hero hero)`